# How to define tuple of types in julia type declaration's

Tags: julia, type-declaration

How do I declare a tuple of specific types for a julia function?

This works:

```
function f(x, y)::Int8
    x+y
end

julia> f(2, 3)
  5
```

This works too:

```
function g(x, y)::Tuple
    x+y, x*y
end

julia> g(2, 3)
  (5, 6)
```

But I can't figure out how to define the types in the tuple.

For example, this throws an error:

```
function h(x, y)::Tuple(::Int8, ::Int8)
    x+y, x*y
end
  ERROR: syntax: invalid "::" syntax around REPL[48]:2
```

An this too:

```
function k(x, y)::Tuple(Int8, Int8)
    x+y, x*y
end

julia> k(2, 3)
  ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Tuple(::Type{Int8}, ::Type{Int8})
```

Comment: Just a comment: You can generally avoid these type annotations altogether and trust that the compiler's type-inference magic will do the job for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use curly braces and omit the `::` for the tuple's elements' types:

```
function k(x, y)::Tuple{Int8, Int8}
    x + y, x * y
end

julia> k(2, 3)
(5, 6)
```